# How does a Juju Oracle create entranced zombies?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, undead, oracle

I am building a necromancer and one of the classes in the construction is the [juju oracle](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/oracle/mysteries/paizo-oracle-mysteries/juju/). These oracles are able to create three special types of undead

Dead Zombies - such as juju zombies, created via create undead.

Living Zombies - requires false death revelation and then creatures under charm person/monster and dominate person appear this way.

Entranced Zombies - unable to find any explanation on how to create these and the effects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You create entranced zombies with Laubo Powder

In that same book, they published *Juju Fetiches*, which includes an item called [Laubo Powder](https://www.aonprd.com/MagicJujuFetishes.aspx):

> **Laubo Powder**
>
> Aura moderate enchantment; CL 10th
>
> Slot genie seal; Price 2,800 gp; Weight —
>
> **Description** Salt, chalk, and powdered bone goes into the creation of this thick powder. When it is smeared over the face of a willing or helpless humanoid, the victim is affected as per the spell dominate person. The victim receives a save against the powder’s effect, but makes it at a –2 penalty. Those who fail the save are affected by the spell and are under the control of the powder’s creator (not necessarily the powder’s user). In addition, the victim cannot articulate beyond making a low moaning, and takes on a death-like pallor, appearing to be a zombie. Spells like detect undead or a minute of uninterrupted examination followed by a DC 20 Heal check reveal that the victim is not actually undead.
>
> Creating a batch of laubo powder provides enough for 3 uses.
>
> Construction Requirements Craft Wondrous Item, dominate person, disguise self; Cost 1,400 gp

Comment: Ah, so it falls under the craft juju fetish revelation, and it wasnt directly listed in the juju page like the others which is why I couldnt find it. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

#### A juju oracle "creates" an "entranced zombie" by using another effect

The oracle mystery [juju](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/oracle/mysteries/paizo-oracle-mysteries/juju/) is introduced with the following text:

> One of the best-known and most feared aspects of juju culture is the juju zombie, an unquestioning and deathless servitor of a juju practitioner. **While most tales of such creatures tell of unholy transformations and cannibalistic corpses, many such “zombies” are actually misidentified victims of other juju magic.** In the rites and rituals of juju, three ways exist to create a zombie.

(Emphasis mine.) The description of Entranced Zombies says

> **The most baffling form of “juju zombies” are those who live, yet are enslaved to the power of a juju practitioner**. Taking on the chalky complexion, shambling gait, and halted vital functions of the undead, these victims only appear dead because of eerie enchantments. Those familiar with juju magic refer to such beings as “laubo.” Although other magic reveals that laubo are not truly undead, **the spells or noxious fetishes of a juju user make them appear so** [i.e. dead] **as they do their master’s bidding.** Such magic fades over time, but often too late for a victim mistaken for the walking dead.

(Emphasis mine.) Then, for example, the supernatural ability **false death** says

> Add *charm person* and *dominate person* to your spell list. You must select these spells using your allotment of spells known. Any creature under the effect of one of these spells or charm monster appears dead to any examiners. Although affected creatures do not detect as undead, they look pale and death-like while under the effects of your magic. Additionally, an affected creature ordered to lie still gains a +20 circumstance bonus on Disguise skill checks to look like a corpse.

So, when taken together, an "entranced zombie" isn't something that's *created* but, instead, the term is shorthand for a creature that's been the subject of one of the juju oracle's weird powers.